# How to open a div based on checkbox switch click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a bootstrap switch and I have a div by the bottom of the switch so when the switch is on I want the div to show and when it's off I want the div to hide. I find some solution which only shows for the checkbox.

How can I do it?

For example, if the switch checkbox is checked, then I need to show the content of div else hide the div.

```css
.tags-list-group {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.tags-list-group .switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
    float: right;
}

.tags-list-group .switch input {
    display: none;
}

.tags-list-group .slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.tags-list-group .slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.tags-list-group input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}

.tags-list-group .slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.tags-list-group .slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.tags-list-group input.success:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #8bc34a;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="tags-list-group">
    <div class="tags-group-card">
        <!-- Default panel contents -->
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item custom-list-group-item">
                User Defined
                <label class="switch ">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="success">
                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item show-content">
        <p>Content 1(hide div)</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple with jquery. Checkout the following example

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $("#content").hide();

    $("#chkbox").click((e) => {
        if ($("#chkbox").is(":checked")) {
            $("#content").show();
        } else {
            $("#content").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="" id="chkbox" />
<div id="content">
    <p>Hidden Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The answer is on the right track, try to use the original components as asked in the question

Answer (score 1):

you can just attach [.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) on the slider and then use [.toggle()](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show/hide element, here is a working snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.show-content').hide();
  $('.slider').click(function(e) {
    $('.show-content').toggle();
  })
})
```

```css
.tags-list-group {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.tags-list-group .switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
    float: right;
}

.tags-list-group .switch input {
    display: none;
}

.tags-list-group .slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.tags-list-group .slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.tags-list-group input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}

.tags-list-group .slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.tags-list-group .slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.tags-list-group input.success:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #8bc34a;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="tags-list-group">
    <div class="tags-group-card">
        <!-- Default panel contents -->
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item custom-list-group-item">
                User Defined
                <label class="switch ">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="success">
                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group-item show-content">
        <p>Content 1(hide div)</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `is on I want the div to show and when it's off I want the div to hide` here you do the opposite

Comment: Fixed it by using `hide()` before the run.

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery you can achieve something like this:

```js
$('.show-content').hide() // Init with hidden .show-content

$('input.success').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.show-content').show()
  } else {
    $('.show-content').hide()
  }
});
```

```css
.tags-list-group {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.tags-list-group .switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  float: right;
}

.tags-list-group .switch input {
  display: none;
}

.tags-list-group .slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.tags-list-group .slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.tags-list-group input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

.tags-list-group .slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.tags-list-group .slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.tags-list-group input.success:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="tags-list-group">
  <div class="tags-group-card">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item custom-list-group-item">
        User Defined
        <label class="switch ">
          <input type="checkbox" class="success">
          <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group-item show-content">
    <p>Content 1(hide div)</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

It's using the function, [.show()](https://api.jquery.com/show/), [.hide()](https://api.jquery.com/hide/#hide) and the [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/#change-handler) event.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you wanted, based on your code. But, in my opinion, you can have a neater one by using [collapse component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/collapse/) of Bootstrap and embedding your switch inside it.

```js
$("#myCustomCheckbox").change(function(){

  // in case the switch is on
  if(this.checked) {
        $("#myDivOfContent").addClass("content-area--show");
        
  // in case switch is off
    }else{
        $("#myDivOfContent").removeClass("content-area--show");
    }
});
```

```css
/*** begin::div of content styles ****/

.content-area {
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
 }
 
 .content-area p {
  padding: 20px;
}
 
.content-area--show {
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 0;
}

.switch {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 }
/*** end::div of content styles ****/

.tags-list-group {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.tags-list-group .switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
    float: right;
}

.tags-list-group .switch input {
    display: none;
}

.tags-list-group .slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.tags-list-group .slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}

.tags-list-group input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}

.tags-list-group .slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

.tags-list-group .slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.tags-list-group input.success:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #8bc34a;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="tags-list-group">
    <div class="tags-group-card">
        <!-- Default panel contents -->
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item custom-list-group-item ">
                User Defined
                <label class="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="success" id="myCustomCheckbox">
                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content-area" id="myDivOfContent">
        <p>Content 1(hide div)</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `prop` to get the `this` checked:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.success').change(function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $(".show-content").show();
    } else {
      $(".show-content").hide();
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.tags-list-group {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.tags-list-group .switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  float: right;
}

.tags-list-group .switch input {
  display: none;
}

.tags-list-group .slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.tags-list-group .slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.tags-list-group input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

.tags-list-group .slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.tags-list-group .slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.tags-list-group input.success:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #8bc34a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags-list-group">
  <div class="tags-group-card">
    <!-- Default panel contents -->
    <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
      <li class="list-group-item custom-list-group-item">
        User Defined
        <label class="switch ">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="success">
                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group-item show-content" style="display:none;">
    <p>Content 1(hide div)</p>
  </div>

</div>
```